# Is there a way to pass data from `ng-repeat` to other element conditionally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I am looping over an array, by the conditional I am finding a value. But how to pass that conditional value to another element?

Example :

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1> //how to get here?
<ul class="naviPrCatgInfo">

    <li ng-repeat='subProject in viewProject.SubProjectIds' ng-class="{'selected' : subProject.Id === subProjectId;}" > //how to pass?
        <a ng-class="subProject.Name | trimSpace" ng-href="" ng-click='changeSubProCat(subProject)'>
            {{subProject.Name}} {{subProject.Id}}
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on it?

Comment: I am looping a data, by conditional i am finding that the correct data to show in the `h1` tag, instead of `li`.  ( still li can have that) how to pass? from the controller we do. but declaring a new variable in controller, i am trying to pass through withing elements if possible

Comment: do you wanted to show selected `subProject.Id` as title?

Comment: yes. you are correct, Is there a way to bind?

Comment: you have declared `subProjectId` in each iteration of `ng-repeat`?

Comment: do you wanted to show selected `subProject.Id` as title? on click you are going to select subproject?

Comment: by default as well on click, both way i need to show. ( actuly this is navigation link, by default i am activation first element, later on by click)

Comment: check the answer which I've added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't declare the new variable inside `ng-repeat`, because that will get added inside the child scope created by the `ng-repeat`.

You need to keep `subProjectId` outside the `ng-repeat` scope so that could be available inside the controller, you need to use `$parent` anotation to place that variable inside the controller scope rather than the `ng-repeat`.

So you can easily filter `viewProject.SubProjectIds` on the basis of `subProjectId` and show the title element there.

**Markup**

```
<h1>{{(viewProject.SubProjectIds| filter: {Id: subProjectId}: true)[0].Name}}</h1>
<ul class="naviPrCatgInfo">
    <li ng-repeat='subProject in viewProject.SubProjectIds' ng-click="$parent.subProjectId = subProject.Id"
       ng-class="{'selected' : subProject.Id === subProjectId}">
        <a ng-class="subProject.Name | trimSpace" ng-href="" ng-click='changeSubProCat(subProject)'>
           {{subProject.Name}} {{subProject.Id}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```